# Applying perspective with GLSL matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, frustum

I am not quite sure what is missing, but I loaded a uniform matrix into a vertex shader and when the matrix was:

```
GLfloat translation[4][4] = {
    {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0}};
```

or so, I seemed to be able to translate vertices just fine, depending on which values I chose to change. However, when swapping this same uniform matrix to apply projection, the image would not appear. I tried several matrices, such as:

```
GLfloat frustum[4][4] = {
    {((2.0*frusZNear)/(frusRight - frusLeft)), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, ((2.0*frusZNear)/(frusTop - frusBottom)), 0.0 , 0.0},
    {((frusRight + frusLeft)/(frusRight-frusLeft)), ((frusTop + frusBottom) / (frusTop - frusBottom)), (-(frusZFar + frusZNear)/(frusZFar - frusZNear)), (-1.0)},
    {0.0, 0.0, ((-2.0*frusZFar*frusZNear)/(frusZFar-frusZNear)), 0.0}
};
```

and values, such as:

```
const GLfloat frusLeft = -3.0;
const GLfloat frusRight = 3.0;
const GLfloat frusBottom = -3.0;
const GLfloat frusTop = 3.0;
const GLfloat frusZNear = 5.0;
const GLfloat frusZFar = 10.0;
```

The vertex shader, which seemed to apply translation just fine:

```
gl_Position = frustum * vPosition;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This was a while back, but how come the thumbs down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for calculating the perspective/frustum matrix looks correct to me. This sets up a perspective matrix that assumes that your eye point is at the origin, and you're looking down the negative z-axis. The near and far values specify the range of distances *along the negative z-axis* that are within the view volume.

Therefore, with near/far values of 5.0/10.0, the range of z-values that are within your view volume will be from -5.0 to -10.0.

If your geometry is currently drawn around the origin, use a translation by something like (0.0, 0.0, -7.0) as your view matrix. This needs to be applied before the projection matrix.

You can either combine the view and projection matrices, or pass them separately into your vertex shader. With a separate view matrix, containing the translation above, your shader code could then look like this:

```
uniform mat4 viewMat;
...
gl_Position = frustum * viewMat * vPosition;
```

Comment: Included a rotate matrix to verify

Answer (score 2):

First thing I see is that the Z near and far planes is chosen at 5, 10. If your vertices do not lie between these planes you will not see anything.

The Projection matrix will take everything in the pyramid like shape and translate and scale it into the unit volume -1,1 in every dimension.

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/

Comment: The comment on the near far pair range was helpful